# Реализация SENTENCE в Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

В Sphinx есть возможность искать по признаку наличия слов в одном предложении. Например, есть текст:

> Вася молодец, съел огурец, т.к. проголодался. Такие дела.

Если запросить

```
молодец SENTENCE огурец
```

То мы найдем этот текст. Если запросить

```
молодец SENTENCE проголодался
```

То мы этот текст уже не найдем, так как видимо в Sphinx реализация разбивки на предложения реализована по-простому и первая попавшаяся тут точка считается концом предложения. Поэтому вопрос.

Как можно настроить в Sphinx более умную разбивку на предложения при подготовке индекса? Подойдет любой вариант - указать что-то в конфигах или подсунуть внешний пакет для разбивки на предложения, например Томита парсер от Яндекса.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Была идея заранее разбить на предложения с помощью Томита парсера и указать Сфинксу, чтобы в качестве разделителя предложений использовался перевод строки, но судя по исходникам Сфинкса, [это вряд ли удастся](https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/blob/master/src/sphinx.cpp#L3967).

Comment: Побывали использовать `stopwords` или они применяются только для строки поиска?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V Мысль интересная. Со `stopwords` сейчас попробовал, но не получилось. Зато получилось с `exceptions`. Попробовал задать `т.к. => тк` и это помогло. Но опять-же, это весьма компромиссный вариант, т.к. грозит лишними склейками предложений, когда аббревиатурой будет заканчиваться предложение ("`Одно предложение и т.п. Другое предложение`").

Comment: stopwords нужны

Comment: @Etki Я попробовал прописать их: `т.к.`, но это не дало эффекта. Как ими правильно воспользоваться в этом случае?

Comment: я не знаю, я, грубо говоря, из теории этот совет выцепил. возможно, сфинкс их применяет после токенизации (в этом случае стоит выкинуть сфинкс и взять lasticsearch)

Comment: До подготовки индекса сфинкс точно применяет `exceptions`, это хорошо сработало, но перечислять всевозможные аббревиатуры (как и стоп-слова) - думаю не тот путь, которым стоит идти, так как заранее всех многообразий не предусмотрю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, которое устроило.

С помощью Томита парсера разбить текст на предложения. Получаем текст, в котором предложения разделены переводом строки.

В каждом полученном предложении удаляем все точки, восклицательные и вопросительные знаки, оставляем только последнюю точку, "?" или "!".

По этим обработанным данным строим индекс в Sphinx. Разбиение на предложения будет происходить нужным образом, так как Sphinx разделяет текст на предложения при нахождении ".", "?" или "!".